# How to keep abline within boundaries of the corrplot?

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I am trying to add an `abline` to `corrplot`, but the line stretches out of the boundaries. How can I keep the line within the `corrplot` axis?

Here is the code:

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method = "circle")
abline(v=c(2.5,5.5), col=c("black", "black"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=c(3, 3))
```

Also how to add x and y labels to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abline` extends through the whole space. But you can use `lines` to specify the starts and ends of each line. The centers of each square in `corrplot` start from (1,1) in the bottom left and increase by 1 with each square. You can use this to get the needed starts and ends for your lines:

```
corrplot(M, method = "circle")
lines(c(2.5, 2.5), c(0, 12), lwd=3, lty=2)
lines(c(5.5, 5.5), c(0, 12), lwd=3, lty=2)
```

To add the labels simply use the `title` function:

```
title(xlab="x label", ylab="y label")
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Dear Karolis, many thanks, i was able to add lines using "segments".